# How to set integer field default to max number +1?

Tags: django, django-models, django-1.9

I used to set the default value of an integer field like this. But with migrations it's not working anymore. What's the proper way to do it?

```
class Rechnung(models.Model):
  nummer = models.IntegerField(default=lambda: Rechnung.objects.latest('id').nummer + 1)
  [...]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can grab this value in the model save method. Save runs for both create and update, so check it's a new object, then set the default if it's new:

```
class Rechnung(models.Model):
  nummer = models.IntegerField()

  def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        if self.id != None:
           # new record
           self.nummer = Rechnung.objects.latest('id').nummer + 1)
           super(Rechnung,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

Another way is to replace lambda with a custom function:

```
def new_num():
   return Rechnung.objects.latest('id').nummer + 1)

class Rechnung(models.Model):
      nummer = models.IntegerField(default=new_num)
```

Note that you provide the callable as a default, so django calls it each time the default is required (like lambda in the previous version)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I need to get it as the default value in the admin in order to verify that it is right.

Comment: updated as a default, just replace lambda with a function

Comment: Actually I'm just trying that after I found a hint in the docs, but now I'm struggling to query "Rechnung" within it's own definition :/

Comment: It's not part of the class, more like a static method. It's a callable, that django calls when it needs the default. A standard queryset. You could call it as you would in any other place in your code. Just like the lambda - function.

Comment: Thank you so much! Turns out what I did wrong was that I used parentheses when I passed the function name as the default.

Comment: I don't think the custom function is save. With concurrent access in the admin it might create multiple entries with the same `nummer` value. In any case, you should add `unique=True` to the field definition to be on the save side, and also because you will probably lookup instances via this field (unique creates an index).

Comment: That's a good hint. Actually I'm the only user for this so there won't be concurrent access, but still I found 1 or 2 duplicates. So I will add it. The German tax office will be grateful. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, the list I could do for the tax office.

Comment: If the Rechnung.objects.count() == 0, this code will fail. So it might need a try/except and default to 1 or similar.